# ¿Cómo hago "git stash" de un solo fichero?

Tags: git

A veces me ocurre que estoy trabajando en una rama de mi repositorio y he hecho cambios significativos en un archivo. No estoy aún para hacer commit, pero quiero cambiar de rama para ver otra cosa.

Lo que hago muchas veces es `git stash -u` para poner en "stash" todos los ficheros no comiteados. Sin embargo, hay veces en que solo quiero hacer "stash" de un fichero concreto, pero no sé cómo.

He probado con:

```
git stash <fichero>
git stash -u <fichero>
```

Pero ninguna de las opciones me funcionó, en ambas me da el error siguiente que lista todas las opciones del comando:

```
usage: git stash list [<options>]
   or: git stash show [<options>] [<stash>]
   or: git stash drop [-q|--quiet] [<stash>]
   or: git stash ( pop | apply ) [--index] [-q|--quiet] [<stash>]
   or: git stash branch <branchname> [<stash>]
   or: git stash clear
   or: git stash [push [-p|--patch] [-k|--[no-]keep-index] [-q|--quiet]
          [-u|--include-untracked] [-a|--all] [-m|--message <message>]
          [--] [<pathspec>...]]
   or: git stash save [-p|--patch] [-k|--[no-]keep-index] [-q|--quiet]
          [-u|--include-untracked] [-a|--all] [<message>]
```

¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3040833/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La solución a partir de Git 2.13 (circa 2017) es:

```
git stash push <fichero>
```

De este modo coge todo el fichero `<fichero>` y lo pone en stash.

---

Si quieres coger trozos de fichero, también puedes usar:

```
git stash push -p -m "mensaje de commit"
```

Que te mostrará el menú interactivo que permite seleccionar unas partes u otras.

Comment: Genial, parece ser una solución más fácil que la que yo aplico. Lo que yo hago es poner en stage todos los archivos y luego quitar de stage los archivos que quiero llevarme al stash. Luego de eso ejecuto `git stash push --keep-index` y con eso los archivos que están en stage se quedan y los que no, se van al stash. Creo que empezaré a aplicar esta forma.